# How configure incoming port in router for Istio Ingress gateway

Tags: kubernetes, routes, openshift, kubernetes-ingress, istio

I try to configure istio ingress using openshift route. As I understand the request path is as follows:

```
request -> route -> ingress service -> gateway -> virtual service -> app service -> app
```

So, I apply follow config:

Route.yml:

```
kind: Route
  ...
spec:
  host: my-app.com
    to:
      kind: Service
      name: ingress-service
      weight: 100
    port:
      targetPort: http
  ...
```

ingress-service.yml:

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
...
spec:
  ports:
    - name: status-port
      protocol: TCP
      port: 15020
      targetPort: 15020
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9080
      targetPort: 9080
  selector:
    app: ingressgateway
    istio: ingressgateway
  type: ClusterIP
```

ingress-gateway.yml:

```
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: ingress-gw
...
spec:
  servers:
    - hosts:
        - my-app.com
      port:
        name: http
        number: 9080
        protocol: HTTP
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
```

ingress-virtual-service.yml

```
kind: VirtualService
...
spec:
  hosts:
    - my-app.com
  gateways:
    - ingress-gw
  http:
    - route:
      - destination:
          host: my-app
          port: 9080
  exportTo:
    - .
```

I dont set up port 9080 in deployment for ingressgateway pod. And it works. But only if I send request to http://my-app.com:80

Where did I go wrong and how to make only path accessible http://my-app.com:9080 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exposed port numbers for external depend on Router(HAProxy) pod listening ports on OpenShift. If you want to 9080 port instead of 80, you should change the port on Router(HAProxy) pod. Or you can handle the port number on LB to use other port numbers.

The access flow is as follows.

```
LB(80, 443) 
   -> Router pod(80, 443) 
      -> Ingress-Gateway pod
         -Through Gateway and VirtualService -> Backend pod
```

Comment: How does this configuration works? In ingress service I only expose port 9080, so why can I access port 80? And what does "targetPort" mean  in Route config in this case?

Comment: @pwflamy why do you think ingress service ports are equal to exposed ports ? External requests are not allowed to access Service network directly. So the Service ports are available only in the internal network, not from external network. All external requests are controlled over by ingress controller(in the case of OpenShift, it's Router pod(HAProxy)). What about check your haproxy configuration using "oc rsh -n openshift-ingress <your ingress router pod name> cat haproxy.config" ? It shows you how to transfer the requests to the backend pods.

Comment: Ok, I understood. One more question: kiali shows a warning that the deployment does not specify all the ports that are in the service. So if i add to ingress deployment "containers.ports.containerPort" the warning will disappear. But why does it work without specifying exposing port?

Comment: @pwflamy Hmm, could you share the details for your issue on Kiali through new ticket ? Traffic routing reality and evaluation on the Kiali is different.